# SSIS Script Task regional settings

Tags: ssis

I am using a script components in my SSIS package and I have noticed a particular behaviour with the culture settings.

The machine's regional settings are English UK, and when I run the script from BIDS, this is picked up correctly. However, when I run the package from a SQL Server Agent Job, culture somehow changes to English US. the LocaleID of the package is correctly set as English (United Kingdom)

Is there any other regional setting I need to add in SSIS/SQL SERVER or the Agent job please?

Comment: You could try to explicitly set a culture in the Script Task.

Comment: Yes ... I think that will be the approach that I will have to take, but it would be good to know if there is any other setting/configuration that I need to be aware of

Comment: I guess it depends on server settings and the account being used to run too, as discussed here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1037197-148-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that the user under which the SQL Server Agent was running needed to be logged-in to the windows. Else, the regional settings would not be correct. No idea why this is the case ... but it works correctly if user is logged in windows.